# Why does the page disappear after I wrapped its component into a Route tag? [ReactJS]

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I tried out to wrap a Login component into the Route tags in React, but now it doesn't show up in the page anymore. Can you tell what's going on, please?

```
import React, {useState, useReducer} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from './components/Login.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  

  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/something">
             <Login />
          </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` component renders its routed component on the `element` prop. Route `children` is used for nesting routes, the nested `Route` components get rendered into an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet).

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/something" element={<Login />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

[Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> Whenever the location changes, `<Routes>` looks through all its
> `children` `<Route>` elements to find the best match and renders that
> branch of the UI. `<Route>` elements may be nested to indicate nested
> UI, which also correspond to nested URL paths. Parent routes render
> their child routes by rendering an `<Outlet>`.
>
> ```
> <Routes>
>   <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
>     <Route
>       path="messages"
>       element={<DashboardMessages />}
>     />
>     <Route path="tasks" element={<DashboardTasks />} />
>   </Route>
>   <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
> </Routes>
> ```
>
> > Note:
> >
> > If you'd prefer to define your routes as regular JavaScript objects
> > instead of using JSX, try useRoutes instead.
>
> The default `<Route element>` is an `<Outlet>`. This means the route
> will still render its children even without an explicit `element`
> prop, so you can nest route paths without nesting UI around the child
> route elements.
>
> For example, in the following config the parent route renders an
> `<Outlet>` by default, so the child route will render without any
> surrounding UI. But the child route's path is `/users/:id` because it
> still builds on its parent.
>
> ```
> <Route path="users">
>   <Route path=":id" element={<UserProfile />} />
> </Route>
> ```